# Copy permissions form source file to file with same name

Tags: copy, file-permissions

I 've got over 1000+ .xls files with names like "65223p.xlsx" and I need to copy permissons from this files to files with same name , but without "p". 
Each file have different permissions than another.
Can you help me? Thanks.

Comment: r u on windows or linux?(or r u using a programming language?)

Comment: I'm using Windows and want to do it in Powershell.